# Unable to trigger function on focus

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a few form fields. When I click within one field I need to trigger a function. So I tried:

```
$('#myInput').focus(function() {
    alert('fired');
});
```

However it didn't work. I think it is due to the way it is added to the page dynamically with, after the initial page load. I've tried attaching this function to other fields, and they work just fine.

So, I've tried

```
$(document).delegate('#myInput', 'click', function() {
```

and

```
$('#myInput').live('focus', function() {
```

and still no luck. Any suggestions? Thanks.

UPDATE --------------------

Still don't know why, but changing it to

```
$('input[name="myInput"]').focus(function() {
```

worked.

Comment: Although you should not use `.live` or `.delegate`, they should work.  Can you show us the problem using jsfiddle?

Comment: Could you post the bit of code adding this dynamically to the page as well? maybe the id's changed if that's an asp:textbox with master page

Comment: That's the problem, when I test the code it works, just not on a couple of fields that are added later...

Comment: It's Zend framework and the IDs seem to be correct. I should try by name... out of ideas.

Comment: try this instead $("input[id$='myInput']").focus(function() {
    console.log('fired');
});​ .Notice the change of $('#myInput') to $("input[id$='myInput']")

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `$('#myInput').focus(...);` will only add this if `'#myInput'` exists when the javascript it first run.

If you are adding `'#myInput'` dynamically after the javascript load, then you need the javascript to add listeners dynamically.

The following will do this:

**Javascript**

```
$('body').on('focus', '#myInput', function() {
    alert('fired');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aYtmS/)**

**[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try with focusin. Maybe will work.